# Django call method on a model with proxy=True

Tags: django, django-models, django-inheritance

So I have a simple Model inheritance, except that the child model is a proxy.
The problem is that in my view, if I do:

```
concept = get_object_or_404(Term, pk=...)
```

and then I call

```
concept.set_siblings('en') # 'en' is the langcode
```

I get an error, because `set_siblings` expects one more parameter(the `relation_type`). The method inside the `Concept` model is getting called. If I print `concept.__class__.__name__` I see `Concept`. So how can I correctly call the `set_siblings` inside the `Term` model?

Here is [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models), but which does not help me to clarify the problem.

**models.py**

```
class Concept(Model):
    namespace = ForeignKey(Namespace)
    code = CharField(max_length=10)
    date_entered = DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_changed = DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    # .....

    def set_siblings(self, langcode, relation_type):
        setattr(self, relation_type + '_concepts',
                self.get_siblings(langcode, relation_type))
    #.....

class Term(Concept):
    def set_siblings(self, langcode):
        for relation_type in ['broader', 'narrower', 'related']:
            super(Term, self).set_siblings(langcode, relation_type)

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = "concept"

    objects = ConceptManager('Concepts')
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `ConceptManager` and any custom queryset if you're using one?

Comment: @knbk yes, the problem was in the `ConceptManager`. In the `get_queryset` method I was using `Concept` instead of `self.model.default_manager`, so the Manager was not aware of the proxy model he belongs to. @Daniel Thanks as well